# How to escape characters inside Ruby array literal shortcuts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi all so I have a simple form. very simple so I don't need to do anything clever. The following code works a treat for what I need. However as you can see I have put dashes between the words to make it read correctly. I have tried putting them between "Service Change" for example to cater for the space I have also tried 'Service Change' but it doesn't read correctly. Am I doing this wrong. Very new to Ruby.

```
<%= f.select :type_of_change, options_for_select(%w[ Service-Change Project-Change Retrospective-Change])%>
```

Comment: "Wow Am I going Mad" is definitely *not* a good title for a question.

Comment: agreed! I was about to edit it.

Comment: What is the actual problem? I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't read correctly".

Comment: On the problem of style, how much of that View stuff could you move to the Model? The list of change types obviously belongs in a constant array in the Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= f.select :type_of_change, options_for_select(%w[Service\ Change Project\ Change Retrospective\ Change])%>
```

Array output:

```
# => ["Service Change", "Project Change", "Retrospective Change"]
```

Comment: grrr...  perfect thanks. I try to resort here when I've pulled all my hair out. And then discover the simple fix. :)

Comment: Done. It wouldn't let me for 3 minutes.